# Stroke detection algorithm in pictures to detect lines and curves

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I am looking for an algorithm that detects all lines including curves etc. in a picture so i can redraw it using my software in a drawing program like paint. For now i only want it to be repainted in black and white. My approach was to make a stencil of the picture and try to read all black pixels as lines and finally paint it. The line calculation goes something like that:

```
 * for every pixel
 *      Point p = (x, y)
 *      List<Point> line
 *      while p is not marked
 *          mark p
 *          p = adjacent darkest pixel //brightness of a pixel is calculated by pixel luminance divided by 2 + luminance of the 8 adjacent pixels divided by 16
 *          add p to line
 *      end while
 *      draw line
 * end for
```

My approach works, but not very well. Some outlines get detected as two lines.

[image: My approach]

Do you have some improvements to my algorithm, or an even better one?

Comment: in my opinion I think that what are you looking for is binarizing your image, and finding the contours or maybe the edges.

Comment: Your question could do with some more focus... what are you actually trying to do? What are the 3 images you present? What language and operating system are you familiar with?

Comment: The left picture is the input, the middle one the stencil of the left one, the last the output of my program. I'm using the Robot class of Java AWT to draw the image in Microsoft Paint.

Comment: Ok, looking first at the middle (stencil) one, how did you make it and why don't you use that? Then, same question again for the right one.

Comment: Using 3x3 filters (like in convolutional filters) and using the standard deviation between all 9 colors as luminance value. I could just draw all dots with certain luminance but that would make the picture look too pixelated and it wouldn't look like the bot is drawing lines.

Comment: Edit: Actually its not 3x3, but a "+", so only 5 values. The right picture uses the pseudocode I used in the original post.

Comment: There are all sorts of horrible artefacts in the yellow thing's mouth - in the red area. Have you saved it as a JPEG somewhere along the way? Could you grab and save the image as PNG to avoid that kind of thing?

Comment: The original source image is jpeg, it doesn't really matter because the stencil creates thick lines that could be interpreted as multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Canny Edge Detection which is a popular edge detection algorithm. It's already implemented in OpenCV as [`cv2.Canny()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html). Using a screenshoted input image, here's the result:

Input image

[image]

Result (inverted and non-inverted version)

[image]
[image]

Here's an implementation in Python OpenCV

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, and perform Canny edge detection
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = 255 - cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)

# Show image
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** To automatically determine the lower and upper thresholds, take a look at [Zero-parameter, automatic Canny edge detection with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/)